# What is the computational complexity of adding two matrix product states?

Tags: quantum-information, tensor-network

I am relatively new to matrix product states (MPS) and I'm interested in the computational complexity of performing an operation of the form A|a> + B|b> where A, B are scalar coefficients and |a>, |b> are quantum states represented by MPS' with some bond dimension $\chi$ and a site dimension $d=2$.

Is it the case that the dominant cost will come from the fact that, after performing addition via a direct sum, the size of the matrices will grow to 2$\chi$ $\times$ 2$\chi$ which will require an SVD sweep in order to reduce the matrices back to the appropriate dimension? If so, what is the computational complexity of performing this SVD sweep?

Edit: I am assuming that |a> and |b> have the same bond dimension, $\chi$ and I want the MPS that results from the addition to also have bond dimension $\chi$.

Comment: Welcome to [Physics.SE].  This question is probably better suited for either [quantumcomputing.SE] or [scicomp.SE]; I suspect that it's unlikely to get an answer here.  I would encourage you to repost this question on one of those sites.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I disagree.

Comment: @QBHS You need to explain *how* you want to add them. Apparently, you would like to do so with some constraint on the bond dimension, i.e. get an approximation to the sum. Could you add the relevant details? Otherwise, the cost is zero, as you just have to juxtapose the two tensors.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch:  I will be happy to be proven wrong.  :-)

Comment: Do you want the optimal approximation to the sum with bond dim $\chi$, or just a good one?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch That depends on the relative complexity of obtaining the optimal approximation compared to a good one. Are you able to give information on both? Thank you